# ParparVM project not working - killed in the simulator

Tags: codenameone

I managed to compile the project generated locally by ParparVM but it is killed a few second after starting.
I notice a few differences between the project generated offline and the one on the server:

1. There are not sources for some classes which are present in the input class ex. `com_codename1_impl_ios_IOSImplementation_15.m` or `com_codename1_system_URLCallback.m`. There are no errors in the log and the classes are parsed. Why is there no cross compiled code in the output directory?
2. In a project generated by a CN1 server I find `Stub.m` and `CodenameOne.m` files but in my project there aren't any Java classes with such names. Are they needed for the iOS project? How they are generated?
3. There are some iOS specific parameters in the `codenameone_settings.properties` CN1 Java project file, shouldn't the ByteCodeTranslator get this file as a parameter to generate the correct project file?
4. The ByteCodeTranslator expects a `public static void main(String[])` in the main class but this function generates an error during the CN1 server build. Why does the ByteCodeTranslator needs this? Can't the code use it if the main class is given as a parameter?

Comment: I suggest splitting those into separate questions in the future as it would be far more convenient to answer 4 smaller questions than one larger question.

Answer (score 0):

1. That is from the iOS port project classes. You need to translate those classes as well. Notice that you will also need to add the native sources from that location.
2. The servers generate a platform native lifecycle class for every platform. That is the "Stub" class. It effectively has a `main` method that calls the main start method. 
   The `CodenameOne.m` files map native interfaces from the [ParparVM](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/tree/master/vm) specific native interfaces to Objective-C in the case of iOS. This keeps native interface binding portable, e.g. these files were generated differently for the old XMLVM port.
3. No it doesn't get it. Most of the stuff is done at a higher level for portability as we needed to do it both for XMLVM and ParparVM.
4. See reply 2.

Comment: 1. That classes were added to BytecodeTranslator (there are parsing messages in log) but in output dirrectory there are no crosscompiled files *.m and *.h.

Comment: 2. So without these files the project can not work? So how can I use ParparVM offline? Is it possible?

Comment: You need to write and compile such a class in Java that implements the main method. Not sure why you aren't seeing the output, are you sure you passed the right output directory.

Comment: Are somewhere any example of *stub.java and *codename.java? XMLVM create stub/glue classes internally maybe ParparVM should do the same? Or maybe CN1 team can share tool which create these code? It is not only main function, they looks quite complicated. Only a few classes is not create at output but this problem I can debug myself but I need know how to create *stub.java and *codename.java without them ParparVM is complete useless!

Comment: The native sources stub is complex, if you use the native code directly you don't really need that as you can call "native" directly or reuse the .m source files from the build servers. We don't have standalone versions of either the stub or the native binding logic since that's deeply embedded into the build process.

Comment: Can you share example *stub.java and *codeone.java files for some demo apps (DrSbaitso and KitchenSink)?

Comment: We don't have those as we auto generate that too on the servers. In the past we had some test code that we used for the VM but that isn't really used anymore.

Comment: How you know files *.m *.h generated by ParparVM cannot be reused because they are changing after each build. The files *stub.java and *codenaone.java are needed to init CN1 framework and to run project. So project without these files can not be run.

Comment: Nowadays it is secret how to create them, no example, and no tools.
 So why you are writing: Once the translation process succeeds you should have a valid xcode project that you can run and use as usual. Or: We saw the true benefits of open source for a project like Codename One: trust. It is simply not true - ParparVM cannot build working project as XMLVM did. If CN1 Team will disappear, I hope not, you clients cannot do anything to use they projects.

Comment: I don't see what's so hard about creating a java source file with a main method that just invokes your init/start method as I explained? Our full code is more elaborate since it includes a lot of additional details that we need there but for a basic app this should work, did you try that?

Comment: May be hello world printing message on console will work but not normal App. You know that *stub.java make such important task like init vtable, display or native classes... Here are errors messages after running my app init from main:
java.lang.NullPointerException at com_codename1_ui_Display.getResourceAsStream:2545
java.lang.NullPointerException at com_codename1_io_Storage.init:79

Comment: The stub doesn't initialize any vtables. Those are done on a per class basis and the stub is written in Java so it has nothing special. The binding to native interfaces is auto generated and e.g. in the kitchen sink there are no native calls so native interfaces aren't bound. These exceptions are because the resources aren't in the build path.

Comment: No exception is because STATIC_FIELD_com_codename1_ui_Display_impl is null. Display is not initialized.

Comment: I think there are two solution: add stub/codenaone creation to ParparVM as XMLVM did or export *stub.java and *codenameone.java folder with other sources (this is very easy just you need add one line to ant script)

Comment: Right the stub also needs to invoke `Display.init(mainClassInstance);` before calling `init(null);`. The stub creation was not a part of XMLVM ever, this was always a part of our server code. You are referring to the work Steve did a few years back for offline build which has nothing to do with us.

Comment: Still not working. I get error:Thread 5:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, adress=0x0) in line (*(functionPtr_java_lang_Runnable_run__)__cn1ThisObject->__codenameOneParentClsReference->vtable[classToInterfaceMap_java_lang_Runnable[__cn1ThisObject->__codenameOneParentClsReference->classId][0]])(threadStateData, __cn1ThisObject);

Comment: stack:virtual_java_lang_Runnable_run__ at java_lang_Runnable.m:63
com_codename1_ui_Display_processSerialCalls__ at com_codename1_ui_Display.m:2857
com_codename1_ui_Display_mainEDTLoop__ at com_codename1_ui_Display.m:2161
com_codename1_ui_RunnableWrapper_run__ at com_codename1_ui_RunnableWrapper.m:470
virtual_java_lang_Runnable_run__ at java_lang_Runnable.m:63
com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneThread_run__ at com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneThread.m:494
virtual_java_lang_Runnable_run__ at java_lang_Runnable.m:63
java_lang_Thread_runImpl___long at java_lang_Thread.m:242
threadRunner at nativeMethods.m

Comment: Looking at the logic a bit it was a bit different than I understood (hard to read the pre-generated code). The stub implements `Runnable` and the init/start etc. are called from run(). The main method is just one line: `Display.init(new MainClassStub());` and this effectively calls the `run()` method on the EDT to start the app loading.